# How to get a parent of caller of obj method?

Tags: javascript

How can i get a function name without knowing it in advance.

```
db = {
    base: {
        getById: function() {
            console.log(methodName);
        }
    }
};
```

I want to call db.base.getById() and console to log 'base';
Please give me a hand :)

Comment: You can't. The function or object could be assigned to multiple properties / variables. It is not a unidirectional relationship.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that.

What you can do is to use a different pattern, for example a factory :

```
db = {
    base: (function(){
        var b = {};
        b.getById: function() {
            console.log(b);
        }
        return b;
    })()
};
```

Comment: I'll probably delete this answer, I'm not sure it's helpful here.

Comment: So ... i can't do as i like it, so i will do it with a factory :)

Comment: Did you notice this logs the whole base object and not the "base" string ? I'm not sure of what you want or need.

Comment: mhm, but i needed the 'base' string.
The idea is to make a 'base' model with methods. And something like this:

db.base -> basic methods like create, getById, getAll
and then
db.person = base

so i can call db.person... and there are the same methods but for 'person' perspective. So i don't duplicate code ...

Comment: Your problem is not very clear to me but don't you need prototype based classes?